# Python Scraping | Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to extract the for each "Date" part, what is the best way to scrape the date part which inside the `<p>`.

```
<div class="kefufloat" id="targetObj">
            <img src=" " width="44"></div>

    <div class="reblock">
        <p><span>运单编号：</span>w44036</p>
        <p><span>下单时间：</span>2020-04-21 14:17:56</p>
        <p><span>到齐时间：</span>2020-04-10 11:33</p>           
            <p><span>已称重时间：</span>2020-04-21</p>        
    </div>
    <style>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) documentation and elaborate what you've tried and where specifically you're facing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this snippet will help you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="reblock">
  <p><span>运单编号：</span>w44036</p>
  <p><span>下单时间：</span>2020-04-21 14:17:56</p>
  <p><span>到齐时间：</span>2020-04-10 11:33</p>           
  <p><span>已称重时间：</span>2020-04-21</p>        
</div>
<style>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(row.get_text())
```

Output looks like this:

运单编号：w44036 
下单时间：2020-04-21 14:17:56 
到齐时间：2020-04-10 11:33 
已称重时间：2020-04-21

for further processing you can use [split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) method to get only Date part of the string. then you can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library to manipulate dates easily. especially [strftime() and strptime(](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)) function can be very helpful.